# Intervention colorize function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, intervention

We are having problem with colorize function in intervention package in laravel. We want to send rgb values not these -100,0,100 or similar. Does anybody have clue about what to do?

This is the code:

```
$img = Image::make('assets/images/part6_v1.png');

$img->colorize(-100, 0, 100);
$data = (string) $img->encode('data-url');

return $data;
```

Comment: What do you think those values are? From the [docs](http://image.intervention.io/api/colorize) - *public Intervention\Image\Image colorize(integer $red, integer $green, integer $blue)*

Comment: Do you know way to convert that to functional rgb?

Comment: any specific error?

Comment: We dont have errors. Wa re getting color but we dont knwo the way to convert rgb values to these values.

Comment: What do you mean by "rgb"? 0 to 255?

Comment: For instance to convert #FF0000 to these values. Every time when we have some color in that format to convert it to these 3 parameters?

Comment: That's hex, not RGB

Comment: Yes, hex,my mistake,sorry.

Comment: You'll have to enter a hex value, convert it to what the function expects and pass the conversion to the function.